# Window resizing causes the second div to overlap over the first

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site, where it contains three divs (one header and two below). Now, when I resize the window the second div **content** gets overlapped on the first **nav**.
Below is the HTML of the code :

```
<div id = "container">
<div id="header">
<center><img src = "images/logo.png" /></center>
</div>
<br />
<div id="nav">
<center><br />
<a href='#'>Index</a><br />
<a href='#'>About</a><br />
<a href='#'>Contact</a>
</center>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    background-color: #121212
}
div#header {
    background-color: #900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
div#nav {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #900;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    width: 24%;
    height: 900px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
div#content {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #488ed0;
    background-color: #900;
    width: 74%;
    height: 900px;
    float: left;
}
a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000000; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M78q4/6/)
How can I adjust such that the second div does not get overlapped over the first when the window is resized and all contents remain fixed with scroll added at the bottom.

Comment: Better use HTML5's `<nav>` for menu items and `<aside>` for content

Comment: The answer is of course: wait five years and use flexbox ;)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the position of below elements while expecting it to adjust.
The default **position** value is **static** which may cause trouble with adjustment.

Making your wrappers **relative** should solve this problem.

Like this:

```
div#header {
    position:relative;
}
div#nav {
    position:relative;
}
div#content {
    position:relative;
}
```

If above doesn't solve the problem, add **float:left;** to above elements together with the **position:relative;**

Comment: It actually worked for me, I had position fixed which was causing conflict.. I changed it to relative and make a little changes in my percentages in every div and that was enough to make it work! Tnx